# How to add (Listen on Apple Music) link on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, itunes-search-api

So basically, i am only trying to embed affiliate links of songs to my website that i am working on as an university project. The website fetches the lyrics of the song along with the albumart and other metadata. The one thing i cant find is that how do i fetch the links like the apple music link to listen to the song. Any help is welcomed

I dont want to go link each and every song. i just need an api that generates the link for me.

Comment: Apple Music [Link Builder](https://tools.applemusic.com/en-us/linkbuilder)

Comment: i dont want to go linking each and every song. i need an api that takes the artist and song name and generates the link

Comment: What about the [Apple Music API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi)?